# Rollup.js - Exclude module from bundle

Tags: config, es6-modules, rollupjs

I've the issue that I can't get the config of my rollup.config.js right. I want to exclude the libModule.js module from bundling. I've tried many configs and setting with no succes so far. Can someone help me please.

Here my folder structure.

```
my-folder
└────src
│    └───index.ts
│    └───libModule.js
│
└────dist
│    └───bundle.js
│
└───rollup.config.js
```

index.ts

```js
import $ from './libModule';

container.appendChild(
  $.element('img', { id: 'image', src: '9592/test_1.png', style: '' })
);
```

libModule.js

```js
export default function $(e) {
  return document.getElementById(e)
}
...
```

rollup.config.js

```js
import path from 'path';
import typescript from 'rollup-plugin-typescript2';
const externalId = path.resolve(__dirname, './src/libModule.js');

export default {
  input: './src/index.ts',
  output: {
    file: './dist/bundle.js',
    format: 'iife',
    name: 'sco',
    sourcemap: true,
    interop: false,
    globals: {
      [externalId]: '$'
    }
  },
  external: [externalId],
  plugins: [
    typescript({
      typescript: require('typescript'),
    })
  ],
}
```

tsconfig.json

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "module": "es6",
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "allowJs": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node"
  },
  "include": [
    "src/**/*"
  ],
  "exclude": ["node_modules"],
  "typedocOptions": {
    "inputFiles": [".src/**/*"],
    "mode": "modules",
    "out": "docs",
    "readme": "none"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem was that you need to mark the correct identifier as external.
you need to handle every import with its correct url so if you import the same module from diffrent urls or locations you need to mark the all as external

```js
import ex from './ex.js'
import ex from '../modules/ex.js'
```

and so on see them as string values

https://github.com/pvissenberg/typescript_workspace/pull/1

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Unfortunately i haven't got it working just yet. I've added my tsconfig.json file. I tried so many things a this point i'm loosing faith.